# CORS not working in rust rocket API when called from angular application

Tags: angular, rust, cors, rust-rocket

I've created a simple rocket API and angular app to test things out. Rocket API works perfectly fine when called from Postman or Insomnia, but when I try to call it from angular app CORS is preventing me even though I configured CORS using `rocket_cors` crate. This is my rocket main function:

```rust
#[rocket::main]
async fn main() {
    let cors = CorsOptions::default()
        .allowed_origins(AllowedOrigins::all())
        .allowed_methods(
            vec![
                Method::Get,
                Method::Post,
                Method::Delete,
                Method::Put,
                Method::Patch,
                Method::Options,
            ]
            .into_iter()
            .map(From::from)
            .collect(),
        )
        .allow_credentials(true)
        .to_cors()
        .expect("error creating CORS fairing");

    let _ = rocket::build()
        //.attach(cors)
        .mount(
            "/",
            routes![get_users, get_user, create_user, update_user, delete_user],
        )
        .attach(cors)
        .register(
            "/",
            catchers![not_found, unauthorized, unprocessable_entity],
        )
        .attach(DbConn::fairing())
        .attach(AdHoc::on_ignite("Diesel migrations", run_db_migrations))
        .launch()
        .await;
}
```

and this is my `Cargo.toml`:

```toml
[dependencies]
rocket = { version = "0.5.0-rc.3", features = ["json"] }
serde = { version = "1.0.126", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0.107"
base64 = "0.21.4"
diesel = { version = "2.0", features = ["sqlite", "r2d2"] }
rocket_sync_db_pools = { version = "0.1.0-rc", features = ["diesel_sqlite_pool"] }
diesel_migrations = "2.0"
rocket_cors = { git = "https://github.com/lawliet89/rocket_cors", branch = "master" }
```

I tried moving around `.attach(cors)` up and down, but to no avail.

This is the route:

```rust
#[get("/users")]
async fn get_users(db: DbConn) -> Result<Value, Custom<Value>> {
    db.run(|c| {
        UserRepository::get_all(c)
            .map(|users| json!(users))
            .map_err(|err|
                match err {
                    NotFound => Custom(Status::NotFound, json!({"status": "error", "reason": "Resource was not found."})),
                    _ => Custom(Status::InternalServerError, json!({"status": "error", "reason": err.to_string()}))
                }
            )
    }).await
}
```

This is the error message in browser:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8000/users. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).
```

Comment: What is the CORS error message you're getting in the browser?

Comment: You need to use `cors.responder()` in your routes, too. Can you share an example of a route where you tried to enable CORS?

Comment: I've edited my question to add route and error message.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://github.com/lawliet89/rocket_cors/blob/master/examples/fairing.rs) example?